# What is the easiest way to create responsive Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, image-processing, responsive-design

I'm working on my first responsive website and I want to know how to make all of the images resize dynamically. I've worked around it for now, but I'd really like to rethink how I did this. Is there a `jquery` plugin for this that is easy to implement (I don't know alot of `js`)? Is there a better way?

[My site](http://smore.rvadv.com/?page_id=60)

Comment: Here is a solution which did this pretty well in my opinion. Maybe you can check his source. Also, i would say it is a more efficent and elegant way to accomplish this without js.
http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-flexible.html

Comment: This is a huge topic in the web design/development community at the moment.

Comment: This looks like he just put  `img: max-width:100%;` and then included a js called imgsizer to accomodate ie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need any js for this - this could be achieved with CSS alone. As you figured out from looking at the source in the link in your comments, all that's needed for dynamically resizing an image is the `max-width` property set to `100%`. However, if you want the image to increase in size dynamically as well then you'll have to use `width:100%`.

See the example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/DEkFg/). You'll notice `max-width` does not go past the image's resolution - on the otherhand `width` ensures the image fills the container (which some see as a disadvantage because they lose the resolution when the width exceeds it's original).

There is a catch though, `max-width` property is not supported in IE6 or below - it was only introduced in IE7. This article [here](http://phydeaux3.blogspot.ca/2006/01/max-width-and-faking-it-for-ie.html) provides a workaround for that though.

Answer (score 1):

But resizing an image through css doesn't make an image responsive.

A 200 kb image will be 200 kb when it is 1000 px wide but also when it is resized by css to 50 px wide.

I would like to see you guys' faces when waiting untill that large images is loaded on your smartphone

Comment: So...do you have a better idea?